# How many possibilites are there to draw n out of 4 balls (order matters, with putting back), if 2balls ogether are only allowed to occur n\2 times?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, stochastic-calculus, computational-mathematics

Given is a set S = {A, C, G, T}. We are interestend in the numbers of elements in the biggest subset from S^n (n natural number), which fulfills the following restriction: The amount of "G" and "C" together occuring in an Sequence is n\2 for even n, and (n-2)/2 for uneven n.

Example 1:
n = 6, even. {C,G} has to occur 3 times.
2 of the acceptet sequences are: (C,A,G,C,T,A) und (G,G,G,A,A,A)
2 of the NOT acceptet sequences are: (A,G,T,A,T,C) und (C,C,C,C,A,A)

Beispiel2
n = 3, not even, {C,G} has to occur 1 time.
2 of the acceptet sequences are: (C,A,T),(A,A,G)
2 of the NOT acceptet sequences are: (C,G,T),(T,A,A)

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange, please consider using LaTeX in your post, for help check: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: The rules are not clear.  Are you saying that the number of G and C can occur at most $n/2$ times for even $n$ and $(n - 2)/2$ times for odd $n$?

Answer (score 0):

Almost half of them will be filled from ${C,G}$.
Specifically in a sequence of $n$ elements,
$\lfloor{n \over 2}\rfloor$  will be filled from ${C,G}$ and
$\lceil{n \over 2}\rceil$ will be filled from ${A,T}$.
Since we should choose $\lfloor{n \over 2}\rfloor$ positions
from $n$ positions to be filled from ${C,G}$ we get

$$
S_n = {n \choose \lfloor{n \over 2}\rfloor}2^{\lfloor{n \over 2}\rfloor}2^{\lceil{n \over 2}\rceil} = {n \choose \lfloor{n \over 2}\rfloor}2^n
$$

(Hope, I understood your question)